# Java error - syntax error on token ";", = expected

Tags: java, syntax

just 1 lesson. I got an error. when mouseover the error it tips up like that "syntax error on token ";", = expected"
Below is my coding, please help me! many thanks friends.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUFq7.png)

```
package HelloWorld;

public class BankAccountManagement {
    private String accountNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String customerName;
    private String email;
    //private String phoneNumber;

    this.balance=100.00;

    public void withdrawn(double amount) {
        if (this.balance < amount) {
            System.out.println("không thể rút dược" + amount);
            System.out.println("chỉ có thể rút dược" + this.balance);
        } else {
            // public void deposit(double amount){
            this.balance += amount;
            System.out.println("bạn gửi thành công" + amount);
            System.out.println("so du hien tại" + this.balance);
            //System.out.println("phone" + this.phoneNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
this.balance=100.00;
```

is a valid line of Java in the right context, but not just on its own. It needs to be inside a method.

The easiest way to achieve what you're trying to do here is to initialize this value when you declare the variable:

```
private double balance=100.00;
```

You can then delete the line that is giving you the problems.

The error message you received was a little confusing, admittedly. It's hard for the compiler always to know what it was you were trying to do. It's also hard for it to tell you succinctly what it was expecting, because there were lots of possible syntactically correct things you might have written at that point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.balance=100.00;
```

That line is freely floating which Java doesn't support. Either move that line code to a Constructor or a block or a method.

Looks like this is default values and I strongly suggest to have a constructor and move that line there.

```
public BankAccountManagement() {
  this.balance=100.00;  
}
```

Comment: Or simply put initialization in declaration.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is the Java tuturial for _this_